# Getting a file through ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have a script in which I need to process a file using ajax.  Everything in the script works, except I can not get the right variable.  I have tried everything and I currently have this in its place

```
title = "<?php echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] ?>";
```

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to successfully set whatever is in this field

```
<label for="file">Thumbnail Pic:</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="file" name="thumbnail" id="thumbnail" />
```

As a variable in the ajax script that I have.  All help is extremely appreciated, thanks for the help!

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
function ajaxupload(){
var ajaxRequest;  

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert('Your browser broke!');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('response');
        ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;

    }
}
var songtitle = document.getElementById('songtitle').value;
var thumbnail = document.getElementById('thumbnail').value;
var name = document.getElementById('file').value;
var title = "<?php echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] ?>";
var description = document.getElementById('description').value;
var params= 'songtitle=' + songtitle + '&thumbnail=' + thumbnail + '&title=' +     title + '&description=' + description + '&name=' + name;
ajaxRequest.open("POST", 'ajaxupload.php', true);  
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
ajaxRequest.send(params);

}

</script>
<div id="centered2">
<h1>Music Upload</h1>
<div id="centered">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<h4><br><?php
echo $echovar10;
 echo $echovar20;
echo $echovar40;
echo $echovar50;
echo $echovar60;
echo $echovar120;
echo $echvoar130;
?><div id='response'></h4>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<label for="file">Choose a song:</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"/> 
</td>
</tr>
<br />
<tr>
<td>
<label for="file">Thumbnail Pic:</label>
 </td>
<td>
 <input type="file" name="thumbnail" id="thumbnail" /> 
<br />
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are you trying to actually upload the file or just send the filename?

Comment: I have the uploading script all set up, I just do not know how to pass the name of the file onto the file upload page.

Comment: Isolate that dump of code to your actual problem.

Comment: You can't upload files through AJAX like that. There is a workaround that involves posting the form to an invisible iframe. I know you aren't using jQuery, but you may find something of use at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

I would really recommend you use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It'll make your life alot easier. Here's the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function documentation. jQuery also provides some wonderfully simple wrapper functions for [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) methods. Google hosts the [code](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js) ([minified](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js)) which is convenient.

```
$.post(
    'ajaxupload.php',          // url
    $("#form_id").serialize(), // data
    function(data) {           // return function on success
        alert(data);
    }
);
```

But as for the real reason you are here, looks like a simple typo.

```
title = "<?php echo $_FILES['thumbnail']['name'] ?>";
```

Comment: I guess that I could use jQuery, but quite literally I hate it.  I just really do not understand it at all and would rather stick with some that I am used to and know how to use.  JQuery just blows my mind; sorry to sound like a noob.  But I will go ahead and take a look at these, thanks!

Comment: So is that all that I write?  I mean do I get rid of my current functions and just paste that over it?  I don't understand how jQuery access the variables of the form.

Comment: Yep, $("#form_id").serialize() should pass in your form data, once you change the form_id the the id of your form. And of course include your <script type="text/javascript" src="[https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js)"/>

Comment: Quick crash course in jQuery, $(something) is how we access elements in our html, where '#foo' gets the first element in the dom with an id of foo, and '.foo' returns an array of all the elements with a classname of foo.